# Given an IOS Bundle ID how do I display the corresponding App Icon

Tags: ios, swift

[image: App Icon List Comparison]

I am storing information about meal timing in Apple's Health App/DB. When I review Apples Health App for meal information (top screen in the image) the source App Icon is included in the list.

When I attempt to do the same in my App (Bottom Screen in the image) it works fine for my Apps BundleID but I cannot retrieve the App Icon from the Health App supplied BundleID for an alternate source App. I am using the code shown below to try to achieve this. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, perhaps the wrong approach, perhaps missing some setup calls (like opening the Bundle before use). I have seen this used in third-party fitness/nutrition apps so there must be some way for doing this. I would appreciate any help or redirection of my effort. Thanks in advance.

```
func getAppIcon(_ theBundleID: String) -> UIImage {
    guard let iconsDictionary = Bundle.init(identifier: theBundleID)!.infoDictionary?["CFBundleIcons"] as? NSDictionary,
        let primaryIconsDictionary = iconsDictionary["CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] as? NSDictionary,
        let iconFiles = primaryIconsDictionary["CFBundleIconFiles"] as? [String],
        // First will be smallest for the device class, last will be the largest for device class
        let firstIcon = iconFiles.first,
        let icon = UIImage(named: firstIcon as String) else {
            return UIImage()
    }
    return icon
}
```

Comment: You can't access data outside of your app sandbox.  The best you can do is add icons into your app bundle for popular/well-known apps or display a generic icon for other apps.

Comment: Be careful. Showing an Apple app icon in your interface can get you thrown off the App Store.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey Paul, thanks for your swift (excuse the pun) responses. You are, depressingly, probably right. I have found other responses here in SO that indicate pretty much the same thing. I have tried to find the other apps that I was thinking of that were able to do this and could only locate the Apple health app and they obviously have access that mere mortals do not. Anyway, I will keep poking around a while longer and report back here if I find anything more positive.

Comment: @matt Hi Matt, thanks for the warning!

Comment: I'm doing the same thing in an app I'm working on. Apple has guidelines for use the Health app icon, e.g., don't use it as a button, etc. So I think it can be used, as long as you stick to their guidelines. It would be nice to be able to use icons for other apps. I've not found a way to do that, though, so instead I'm using a blank icon that's colored according to a hash of the app bundle id.

Comment: BTW, is your app published, and are you using the Health app icon?